# Access 2003 pass-through query to Oracle "Syntax error in JOIN operation" but can't find error?

Tags: sql, oracle, ms-access, pass-through

Good morning all,

I'm trying to get this pass-through query via ODBC to our Oracle database to work in Access 2003 but it gives a "Syntax error in JOIN operation" :

```
SELECT "WO_OPERATION"."SI_NUMBER",
       "WO_TASK"."SEQUENCE",
       "WO_STATUS"."DESCRIPTION",
       "APPLICATION_CODES"."APPLICATION_CODE"
FROM ("QCTL"."WO_TASK_STATUS" "WO_TASK_STATUS"
      INNER JOIN ((("QCTL"."WO_OPERATION" "WO_OPERATION"
                    INNER JOIN "QCTL"."WO_TASK" "WO_TASK" ON "WO_OPERATION"."WOO_AUTO_KEY"="WO_TASK"."WOO_AUTO_KEY")
                   INNER JOIN "QCTL"."PARTS_MASTER" "PARTS_MASTER" ON "WO_OPERATION"."PNM_AUTO_KEY"="PARTS_MASTER"."PNM_AUTO_KEY")
                  INNER JOIN "QCTL"."APPLICATION_CODES" "APPLICATION_CODES" ON "PARTS_MASTER"."APC_AUTO_KEY"="APPLICATION_CODES"."APC_AUTO_KEY") ON "WO_TASK_STATUS"."WOT_AUTO_KEY"="WO_TASK"."WOT_AUTO_KEY")
INNER JOIN "QCTL"."WO_STATUS" "WO_STATUS" ON "WO_TASK_STATUS"."WOS_AUTO_KEY"="WO_STATUS"."WOS_AUTO_KEY"
WHERE ("WO_TASK"."SEQUENCE"=120
       OR "WO_TASK"."SEQUENCE"=172)
  AND ("APPLICATION_CODES"."APPLICATION_CODE"='OEM'
       OR "APPLICATION_CODES"."APPLICATION_CODE"='PL')
  AND "WO_STATUS"."WOS_AUTO_KEY" =3
ORDER BY "WO_OPERATION"."SI_NUMBER",
         "WO_TASK"."SEQUENCE"
```

The query works fine in the Oracle database and another pass-through query also works fine. When Access throws up the error it selects the DOT in this line:

```
FROM ("QCTL"."WO_TASK_STATUS" "WO_TASK_STATUS"............................
```

I don't have a clue what is wrong, does anybody have the eagle eye here? :)

Thanks!

Rob

Comment: Try removing the quotes around the field names ?
Are you using MS Driver for Oracle or Oracle driver ?

Comment: Does not work, removed all the qoutes in the query and it says: "can't find QCTL.mdb" I have another pass-through query with the same quoting and that works perfectly in Access. I think I use the Oracle 11g driver, not sure though but that is the driver assigned to the ODBC connection if that is what you meant ;)

Comment: Pfff I feel a bit ashamed right now... Turned out I forgot to mark it as pass-through query in Access. I checked everything the last two days but never for that as it is just too obvious :P
Thanks for your time though!!